# In IE, opening MS Office files asks for a certificate and then shows blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

When I try to open MS Office files on my website I first get a popup that says "The website you want to view requests identification. Please choose a certificate"  I have "Ignore Client Certificates" checked, and the only other answer I've seen involves playing with the registry which I'd like to avoid.

Even more annoyingly, if I click OK or Cancel in the popup, it then continues on and opens a blank page/spreadsheet/whatever.  I know the files aren't corrupted cuz I can download and then open them perfectly through firefox/chrome, and non-MS Office files open fine everywhere.

Neither of these issues occur on my local computer, so I'm assuming it's a setting and/or SSL problem.  Displaying files is something I use all over my site, so this is a *major* bug for me.

Comment: So..i would be interessting how you open the files. How do you achieve that? This is maybe useful information...

Comment: I block direct access and instead have buttons that open a page with the following code in Page_Load:

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sOutputName);
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
doc.Load(fileName);
//Get file type based on XML file lookup (no here cuz of char count)
if (type != "")
  Response.ContentType = type;
else 
  Response.ContentType = "text/html";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fi.Name + "\"");
Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

Comment: and 
<body onload="GetFName();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="flname" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetFName() 
        {   
            document.getElementById('flname').value = window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fname').value;
            document.form1.submit ();
            window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fname').value = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>